# Drop off equations when transform equations from DAEs to ODE by structural_simplify of ModelingToolkit

Tags: julia, ode, modelingtoolkit

I tried to create ODE equations from DAEs by ModelToolkit.ji. However, after using `structural_simplify()` function, there are several equations have been dropped down. (The equations drop from 56 to 49).
Please help me to address this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended. `structural_simplify` simplifies the structure by deleting redundant equations. You can get them out of the solution via symbolic indexing.

Comment: I used the code below to solve the DAEs. 
`@named sys = ODESystem(eqs); 
prob = ODEProblem(sys,u0,tspan);
sol = solve(prob)`
and got the message:
"retcode: InitialFailure
Interpolation: specialized 3rd order "free" stiffness-aware interpolation"
How could I fix it?

Comment: That means you got a failure in the DAE initialization process. We would need to see your model in order to know why.